# google maps traffic info

Tags: google-maps

Google maps in some region can serve traffic information showing the blocked roads and so on. I was wondering if there is any code example demonstrating how can I serve traffice information for my own region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Google Maps Hacks" has a hack, ["Hack 30. Stay Out of Traffic Jams"](http://safari.oreilly.com/0596101619/googlemapshks-CHP-4-SECT-3), on that.

You can also find out how to get U.S. traffic info from John Resig's ["Traffic Conditions Data"](http://ejohn.org/blog/traffic-conditions-data/) article.

Comment: I would like to create similar sites what are shown in the hacks but for regions where there is no information from google yet.

Answer (score 1):

For your own data, you'll want to implement a [custom tile overlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Tile_Overlays).

Answer (score 0):

Google is mum on what source they use for their traffic data.  You might contact them directly to see if they want to implement something for you, but my guess is that they'd simply refer you to their provider if they really wanted your data.

Keep in mind that traffic data is available for more than just the metropolitan areas, but Google isn't using it for a variety of reasons - one of the big reasons is that the entire tile set for the traffic overlay in areas with traffic tiles has to be regenerated every 15 minutes or so.  It just doesn't scale.

So even if you managed to get your data in their flow, it likely won't be rendered.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

I found that googl has a class called GTrafficOverlay and this is based on extending the GOverlay class. Now, it is getting clearer that I am looking for an open implementation of the GTrafficOverlay